# React - Changing multiple, individual components via one other component with Context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

Let's say I have three components: `App`, `Block` and `BlockOptions`.

`App` has an array called `blocks` that holds all block components. These blocks are rendered inside some kind of artboard. Because each block can be modified, I want `BlockOptions` to act as a properties panel whenever a `Block` is selected. That `Block` should be able to be modified from there. Remember that `BlockOptions` is at a completely different location.

App.js:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      artboardSize: {
        width: 300,
        height: 200
      },
      blocks: []
    }
  }
  // App component contains several methods that change the blocks array, like this one
  addBlock(width, height) {
    const newBlock = {
      width: width,
      height: height
    }

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      blocks: [...prevState.blocks, newBlock]
    }));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <GlobalContext.Provider value={this}>
        <div className="app">
          <Artboard /> // Where all Blocks go
          <Sidebar /> // Where BlockInfo goes
        </div>
      </GlobalContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

As seen above, I'm using Context API to give all components access to `App`'s state and methods.
So, for example, if click on a button somewhere on the page, that component calls `App`'s `addBlock()` method to create a new block.

This is how I'm currently rendering each block in `Artboard`:

```js
{context.state.blocks.map((block, key) => (
  <Block key={key} width={block.width * context.scale} height={block.height * context.scale} />
))}
```

In Block.js, I want to change `App`'s blocks array with `selected` to `true` when the user clicks on a block:

```js
class Block extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      width: this.props.width,
      height: this.props.height,
      selected: false
      // etc...
    }
  }
  handleOnClick() {
    this.setState({
      selected: true
    });

    // But how do I update this in App?
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="block" onClick={() => this.handleOnClick()}></div>
    )
  }
}
```

But I can't. I can update the state **within** `Block`, but not in the whole App itself. How do I go about this?

I'm pretty new to React. So maybe using the Context API isn't suited, I really don't know. Maybe my whole way of thinking is messed up. Maybe there's a better way to tackle this?

**Basically what I'm trying to do:**
Have a set of components, each different from one another, to be able to be changed from some kind of 'Options Panel'. Each block is different, so this panel should change according to the selected block's state.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you decide to use context, reducer, or state, you'll need to pass a function to your block component that will be called by the top level component to update the value is passes down to the children.

If you want to use context, you could change the value to:

```
<GlobalContext.Provider value={{ blocks: this.state.blocks, addBlock: this.addBlock }} >
```

That way, any consumer of the context not only has access to the blocks, but also a function to call to update them for any other consumers across the app.

```
{context.blocks.map((block, key) => <Block ... onAdd={context.addBlock} />)}
```

And within the block:

```
handleOnClick() {
  this.setState ...
  this.props.onAdd();
}
```